# Thread vs AlarmManager which one has low battery usage

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

What I need in my application is do some stuff every 30 sec for 18 hours per day which I want to keep running even device going to sleep mode
for that I found two ways:

1. Using timer using the `AlarmManager` with a type of `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`
2. Using a thread with a unfinished while-loop and sleep for thread every 30 seconds.

Now I am using timers, that works fine in all API versions but have one problem and that's battery usage.

My question is, can I use a thread instead of timers?  I heard somewhere threads cannot run for very long times (5sec max), but I'm not sure.
And if I can use thread, is that take lower power than timers?
and works for all API versions?

Comment: it is AlarmManager ....

Comment: It is a bad idea to to something every 30 seconds. Of course if drains your battery (and using alarmmanager already is the best way to prevent it). I honestly think you should rethink your concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good description of your question
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html